# How to remove certain characters to separate the Ids

Tags: android

I have the following strings and would like to remove all characters before the = sign to retrieve the two usernames. I guess I am confused because I can do this with a single username but for more than one username and with a comma? Sounds confusing..

I am not sure if I need to use any splitting method here.. I might have been doing this wrong but how would I retrieve all values under ID? the id has a number after it....

{Id91=piano0011, Id111=musician8888}

I tried doing something like this but it only returns"musician8888}"...

String Id = Id.replaceAll(".+=", "");

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ42T.png)

Comment: I have reduced it down to the following: piano0011 111musician8888

Comment: I have done something like this but I am not sure if this will work in the future for all usernames

Comment: Id = Id.replaceAll(",", "");
                        Id = Id.replaceAll("=", "");
                        Id = Id.replaceAll("Id", "");
                        Id = Id.replaceAll("[{}]","");
                        Id = Id.substring(2);
                        Id = Id.split("\\s* \\s*")[0];